# fgets give me random big number

Tags: c

This is my code, I don't know how to use `fgets` after `scanf` so I am using `fgets` in the 26th line too but every time I use it, it give me big number(ex.2752100) but I write 2.

Why is it doing it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char veta[100];
  int line = 1;//tell what line it is on
  int found = 0;
  char a[100];//put the characters of the line into here
  char b[100];
  char linesearch[10];//the line you are looking for
  FILE *file;//the file pointer
  file = fopen("text.txt","r");//point the file
  if (file == NULL)
  {
    printf("file does not exist or doesn't work\n");
    return 0;
  }

  printf("Ahoj, naucim te psat snadno a rychle! \n");
  printf("Vyber si uroven slozitosti od 1 do 10:\n");
  //scanf("%d", &linesearch);
  fgets(linesearch,10,stdin);
  printf("\nHledam uroven %d ...\n\n",linesearch);
```

EDIT:

i have another problem:

```
while(fgets(a,100,file))
{
if(x == line)
{
found = 1;
printf("level %d found,level %d say: %s",x,x,a);
}
else
printf("reading level: %d\n",line );
line++;
}


printf("\nwrite your string as fast as you can!!");
fgets(veta,40,stdin);

if (strcmp(veta,a) == 0)
{
    printf("\nwell done!!!!\n");
}
else
{
    printf("\nwrong!!!!\n");
    printf("%s", a);
    printf("%s", veta);
}
```

i have small senteces(ex I like my mum and she likes me,etc) i want to compare my text with text from file and get answer if I write it well or not. Bonus points if it tell me how many mistakes i did it will be powerful!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fgets()` function reads character data from the input. To convert this character data to an integer, use `atoi()` or a similar function.

```
fgets(linesearch, 10, stdin);
int x = atoi(linesearch);
printf("\nHledam uroven %d ...\n\n",x);
```

Your `printf` statement is printing out the *address* of the `linesearch` array, which will seem like a random big number.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read from stdin, into a char array, using scanf() and then print as an int:

```
scanf("%s", linesearch); // e.g. reads 1234 into array linesearch[].
printf(" %s ...\n\n",linesearch); // Prints string in array linesearch[].
printf(" %p ...\n\n",linesearch); // Prints base address of linesearch[].

int iNum = atoi(linesearch); // Converts string "1234" to number 1234.
printf(" %d ...\n\n",iNum); // Prints the converted int.
iNum++; // Can perform arithmetic on this converted int.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a big number from printf because you used `%d` in the format. The number is the memory address of your character array. To print the character array, update the format to `%s`.